# selenium + python loop for dynamic drop down boxes

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following loop to navigate thru multiple dynamic drop down boxes, submitting it to reach another webpage, then returning to the initial page to iterate thru all the options.

Problem is that I need to insert in a line to direct the browser to the initial page before every loop. Hence the slow execution speed. Any ideas on improving the code?

Example of the code below:

```
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ID'))
options = select.options

for index in range(1, len(options):
   driver.get('webpage') # issue for slow execution speed
   select.select_by_index(index)
   select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ID2')) # can only select after selecting the first drop down box
   options2 = select2.options

   for index2 in range(1, len(options2):
     driver.get('webpage') # issue for slow execution speed
     select.select_by_index(index)
     select2 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ID2'))
     options2 = select2.options
     select2.select_by_index(index2)

     submit() # click on button to navigate to another page, read data then back to loop
```

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking for. General improvements?

Comment: would like to know is there a way to speed up the loop process coz I have to iterate thru 6 dynamic drop down boxes and I need to insert the line to refresh the webpage at the start of every loop

Comment: Get a faster internet connection? Or run it in parallel